# ca-certificates-java error on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: apt, package-management, dpkg, java

I can't install anything, it gives this error on every installation

```
Setting up ca-certificates-java (20190405ubuntu1) ... 
head: cannot open '/etc/ssl/certs/java/cacerts' for reading: No such file or directory Error occurred during initialization of boot layer
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: ja~a/io/File$PathStatus (wrong name:
java/io/Fil e$PathStatus) dpkg: error processing package
ca-certificates-java (--configure):  installed ca-certificates-java
package post-installation script subprocess retu rned error exit
status 1 Processing triggers for ca-certificates (20210119~20.04.1)
... Updating certificates in /etc/ssl/certs... 0 added, 0 removed;
done. Running hooks in /etc/ca-certificates/update.d...
 
Error occurred during initialization of boot layer
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: ja~a/io/File$PathStatus (wrong name:
java/io/Fil e$PathStatus) E:
/etc/ca-certificates/update.d/jks-keystore exited with code 1. done.
Errors were encountered while processing:  ca-certificates-java E:
Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I tried `dpkg --force-depends --configure ca-certificates-java` but couldnt solve the issue

Answer (score 0):

You are probably have to recreate removed directory by

```
sudo mkdir /etc/ssl/certs/java/
```

and then reinstall packages which have files in the above directory by

```
sudo apt install --reinstall -o Dpkg::Options::="--force-confask,confnew,confmiss" --reinstall ca-certificates-java ssl-cert openssl ca-certificates
```